# Tracking Email Reads for Gmail using HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, email, gmail, httpmodule

I'm successful in creating an application for Tracking Email Reads using ASP.NET by following the below url

> http://www.aspnetemail.com/samples/emailtracker/

Everything is working fine but its not working with Gmail. Gmail is appending its own path in src attribute.

![Gmail appended src] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NfqL.png

Need your suggestions on further approach to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed my image in a local folder and it is working fine for yahoo but not in Gmail.
I solved this, just by putting the image in a [public domain folder](http://www.codeview.in/2017/03/how-to-track-email-in-aspnet-using-httpmodule.html).